# How to get documentation comments from a file by using RegEx?

Tags: regex, documentation, code-documentation

Let's say I have a HUGE file. This huge file contains a bunch of code. In this code every function is documented in XML format. Each documentation is enclosed in 'documentation comments' (/** and **/). I want a regular expression that will remove all code that is not between documentation comments (that would also include the documentation comments but I can remove them afterwards if needed).

Example of part of the script:

```
/**--------------------------------------------------------------------------**\
<summary>FunctionName</summary>
<returns>
    Returns 1 on success.
    Returns 0 on failure.
</returns>
<remarks>
    This function is a function.
</remarks>
\**--------------------------------------------------------------------------**/

int FunctionName()
{
    int X = 1;
    if(X == 1)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
<summary>FunctionName</summary>
<returns>
    Returns 1 on success.
    Returns 0 on failure.
</returns>
<remarks>
    This function is a function.
</remarks>
```

Comment: So you want to create a document consisting of the documentation comments alone?  Don't think of it as *removing* or *excluding* the parts you don't want,  just match the parts you **do** want and write them to a new file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
/^\/(\*\*-+\*\*)\\$(.*?)^\\\1\/$|./gsm
```

and replace with `$2`.

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/fA8bP0/1

The trick is basically the same as in [Regex Pattern to Match, Excluding when… / Except between](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23589204/7586) - use alternation to match what we need, and skip over everything we don't want.

Some notes about the pattern:

- `^` and `$` are not strictly needed - it depends on whether the comments are on a whole line. You can remove them, and remove the `/m` (multiline) flag.
- `\/(\*\*-+\*\*)\\` matches a whole line of a comment, `/**-------**\`.
- We assume these is the same number of hyphens at the beginning of the block as at the end, and capture it to `\1`. If this is not correct, use `\*\*-+\*\*` again instead of `\1`. If you have a fixed number of hyphens, you can use `-{74}`.
- The interesting content is captured to `$1`.
- Everything else is matched by the `.`, and replaced away.
- Caveat: this pattern may fail in the usual ways - strings that contain `"/**-"`, commented code that looks like documentation, escaped characters, etc.